# Should I remove almost all users in Ubuntu?

Tags: ubuntu, security, users

I want to defend my ubuntu server from unauthorized logins. I have an all users list. There are a lot of users. You can see a list on screenshot. **Should I remove all the users except mine?**

I want to do it but I dont wanna to break down a system. Thanks!

[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/upVCh.png)

Comment: No, you should not just remove those users. Most of them are system users and necessary for the system to run. Check https://askubuntu.com/questions/984912/how-to-get-the-list-of-all-users-who-can-access-a-server-via-ssh

Comment: In future, please do not post images of text, they are impossible for users that need screen readers to read. Post the text and use the tool bar to format it if needed